# How do I use a wait between functions Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
public class Bomb : MonoBehaviour
{
     IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            other.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
            Destroy(gameObject);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(5);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to load a scene after 5 second of the `OnTriggerEnter` function.

The particle system is working, the destroying of the object is working.

It's a bomb, I want it to have time to explode before transitionng to the other scene then go to the *Loss screen*

Comment: Are you just trying to wait between functions?

Comment: yes, wait between the destroy function and the scene loading

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add IEnumerator to your trigger event and expect it to be called as a coroutine. This is untested code and from memory, but you'd want to do something like this:

```
public class Bomb : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            other.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
            Destroy(gameObject);
            yield return StartCoroutine (DelayedLoadLevelCoroutine (5,3f));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator DelayedLoadLevelCoroutine (int sceneBuildIndex, float delaySeconds)
    {
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(delaySeconds);
       SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneBuildIndex);
    }


}
```

Also, any particular reason you are using LoadScene with a build index rather than name? Seems name might make more sense in this context:

```
LoadScene("LossScreen")
```